# my rundeck job is not letting me pass all the parameters, just one, and I need all

Tags: rundeck

I use this but only get a SINGLE PARAMETER, passed to the rundeck job:

... ${option.ticketnumber} ...

I want ALL the parameters (not just ONE) so that I can parse them within my code
free and CLEAR of Rundeck.

Anyone want to comment out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your steps using key/value data with a regex to generate a set of data variables like [this](https://youtu.be/ao2SvpspWl4?t=175) to use in your workflow (in this way you avoid to define individual options to pass later). Here a job definition example:

The job that generates the data values:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description>Regex and data passing demo.</description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>a0daf1e3-e918-43dc-b232-bc46a7a287b6</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>Regex</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>env</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo ${data.SHELL}</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo ${data.USER}</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo ${data.PWD}</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref name='AnotherJob' nodeStep='true'>
          <arg line='-option1 ${data.USER}' />
          <uuid>4932f9c7-a435-4332-8b1a-5ade41da9edd</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
      <pluginConfig>
        <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
          <config>
            <logData>true</logData>
            <regex>^(SHELL|USER|PWD)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
          </config>
        </LogFilter>
      </pluginConfig>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>a0daf1e3-e918-43dc-b232-bc46a7a287b6</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

The job that gets the data values:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='option1' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>4932f9c7-a435-4332-8b1a-5ade41da9edd</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>AnotherJob</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "the user from Regex Job is ${option.option1}"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>4932f9c7-a435-4332-8b1a-5ade41da9edd</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

But to get it (passing) from another job, you need to set individual options using a [job reference step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step) with option as arguments.

Comment: I run your job like this, rd run --job "Regex" $* in a bash script,but don't see the job passing the parameters $* but do see a "PWD" and "/" as a key pair. Also I am not sure how I would use this job to pass parameters to an additional step which is a Bash script which will then act on them. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Sorry, I put only that job definition to show the way to generate data options without creating "normal options", I updated my answer with a more complete example.  I think that works if you are using one job and you want to pass data between steps (and keep your script "clean"). Anyway,  if you need to pass to another job, you need to create options to "receive" that data values.

Comment: I used the second above but it gives the error "the user from Regex Job is " in reply to rd run --job 'AnotherJob' 1 2 3 4 ----- shouldn't i have given "the user from Regex Job is 1 2 3 4" instead of blank?

Answer (score 0):

I programmed around all of this to avoid the restrictions of the interface.